# Python data structure problem next_node type problem?

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to set data into my linked list. but what is the problem in my code? How can i add a new linked list?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head_node=None):
        self.head_node = Node(head_node)

    def add_new_head(self, new_head_node):
        # --------> what line of code goes here?
        
        self.head_node = new_head_node
        new_head_node.next_node = self.head_node
li= LinkedList(4)
li.add_new_head(5)
li.add_new_head(6)
print(li)
```

Comment: By updating next node after self.head_node you are creating a loop, i.e. the head always points to itself. (of course I'm assuming this is an excercise to have a better understanding, otherwise you should use collections.deque)

Comment: @PaoloJ42, thank you. this is an exercise.how  can i add next node with this code?

Comment: Just swap the two lines inside add_new_head. This is a standard excercise, so you will find help online (https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/data-structures-and-algorithms/python-linked-list-exercise-1.php)

Oh yeah, you also need to either pass a node and not a value to add_new_head or add as first line '''new_head_node = Node(new_head_node)'''

Comment: @PaoloJ42, like this:    "def add_new_head(self, new_head_node):
        # --------> what line of code goes here?
        new_node = Node(new_head_node)
        new_node.next_node = self.head_node
        self.head_node = new_node"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues:

- The names of the parameters `head_node` and `new_head_node` are misleading: these are not instances of `Node` as their names suggest, but are *values* (integers) to be used for *creating* nodes. So maybe call them `head_value` and `new_head_value`

  Probably because of this misnaming, you do `self.head_node = new_head_node`, but that will assign an integer to an attribute that is supposed to be a node reference. In the `__init__` method you did it correctly, and first created a Node and then assigned *that* to `self.head_node`. The same should happen in `add_new_head`.
- The assignment `new_head_node.next_node = self.head_node` comes to late: by that time `self.head_node` is already equal to `new_head_node`, and so (if the previous error were corrected), this would create a circular reference.
- Not a problem, but as your `Node` constructor allows for an optional argument for the *next* node, you could make use of this in `add_new_head`, making the code rather elegant.
- Your `LinkedList` constructor *always* creates a node. This is not right, as this way you cannot make an *empty* linked list. It is not really clear to me why you would pass a value to this constructor. Either don't have this parameter, or allow *multiple* values to be passed as argument. There is no reason why you need this constructor to allow for *one* value.
- `print(li)` will not display something that is useful. To get some readable output, implement the `__repr__` method so it returns the list as a string (that can be printed with `print`)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):  # No extra parameter: just create an empty linked list
        self.head_node = None

    def add_new_head(self, new_head_value):  # argument is a value
        # Create node with Node constructor, and use second argument to link it
        self.head_node = Node(new_head_value, self.head_node)  

    def __iter__(self):  
        node = self.head_node
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next_node
            
    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(map(repr, self))  # This uses __iter__

li = LinkedList()  # No arguments here. Use `add_new_head` for adding values
li.add_new_head(4)
li.add_new_head(5)
li.add_new_head(6)
print(li)
```

#### Explanation of `self.head_node = Node(new_head_value, self.head_node)`

This code calls the `Node` constructor, providing it also with the optional argument. For instance, in the above main program, the situation after having inserted two nodes is as follows:

```
┌─li────────────┐
│ head_node: ─────┐  
└───────────────┘ │
                  │
                ┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐
                │ val: 5    │   │ val: 4    │
                │ next: ────────┤ next: None│
                └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

When we call `li.add_new_head(6)`, and execute `Node(new_head_value, self.head_node)`, then the constructor will run and will get the value 6 as argument, and a reference of the current head node, i.e. the node with value 5. The constructor will initialise the new node as illustrated below:

```
┌─li────────────┐
│ head_node: ─────┐  
└───────────────┘ │
                  │
┌───────────┐   ┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val: 6    │   │ val: 5    │   │ val: 4    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

Note that it has its `next` referencing the current head node. The constructor *returns* a reference to the new node, and so the `add_new_head` function will assign it to `self.head_node`, which results in:

```
┌─li────────────┐
│ head_node: ─────┐  
└───────────────┘ │
      ┌───────────┘
┌─────┴─────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val: 6    │   │ val: 5    │   │ val: 4    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

...and that completes the action.

Comment: thank you. how here work node constructor  self.head_node = Node(new_head_value, self.head_node)

Comment: It executes the `__init__` method of `Node`, providing also `next_node` argument. Nothing special. Just see what that function does.

Comment: Added a visualisation of what happens to my answer.